# Applying threshold on both positive and negative elements of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, threshold

suppose I have a Matrix like this:

A=[-3 -4 -5 -6 0 2 3 3 4 5 8 9 10]

Now I want to extract a Matrix whose positive value will be greater than 8 and all other +ve value less than 8 will be zero. And its -ve values will be less than -5 and all other -ve values will be zero. That means something like this:

**A= [0 0 0 -6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 10]**

How to do that?

I have tried the below things

A(A<8)=0

it gives 
A=[ 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    8     9    10]

but my negative values are gone.

if i try

A(A>-5)=0

then I get;

A=[ 0     0    -5    -6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0]

But here all +ve values are gone. 
plz help..

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
A(A<8 & A>-5) = 0
```

Also shown in the documentation [Find array elements that meet a condition](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)

EDIT:
If, as pointed out in the comment, and in how you describe you desired result, you want all values less than or equal to 8 and greater than or equal to -5 to be 0, the answer is

```
A(A<=8 & A>=-5) = 0
```

Comment: `A(A<=8 & A>=-5) = 0` to generate what the OP wrote for his desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, try using the AND operation

```
A=[-3 -4 -5 -6 0 2 3 3 4 5 8 9 10];
A(A > -5 & A < 8) = 0;
```

This would give you the desired result.

Greetz